# String to array and take individual value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this is simple one . But i get confused  . That's why i posted here .

Please see my html structure

```
<li class="1-li normal"><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
<li class="2-li normal"><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
<li class="3-li normal"><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
<li class="4-li normal"><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
<li class="5-li normal"><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
```

and i have a string in javascript

```
  var strintg_value="a.html+a.jpeg*b.html+b.jpeg*c.html+c.jpeg*d.html+d.jpeg*e.html+e.jpeg";
```

here  i can split the strintg_value using * make it as array so

```
   strintg_value[1]="a.html+a.jpeg";
   strintg_value[2]="b.html+b.jpeg";
   strintg_value[3]="c.html+c.jpeg";
   strintg_value[4]="d.html+d.jpeg";
   strintg_value[5]="e.html+e.jpeg";
```

and at the end i need to give appropriate  value for a href and img src like this

```
<li class="1-li normal"><a href="a.html"><img src="a.lpeg"></a></li>
<li class="2-li normal"><a href="b.html"><img src="b.jpeg"></a></li>
<li class="3-li normal"><a href="c.html"><img src="c.jpeg"></a></li>
<li class="4-li normal"><a href="d.html"><img src="d.hpeg"></a></li>
<li class="5-li normal"><a href="e.html"><img src="e.jpeg"></a></li>
```

please help to solve this.

I tried this one `strintg_value=strintg_value.split('*');` 
after that i don't know how to execute the rest .Please help .

Comment: What code have you tried? `split()`ting the string sounds like a good first step, please show us your attempt.

Comment: Careful when doing this : strintg_value=strintg_value.split('*'); Keep your strintg_value a string and declare a new variable for your array.

Comment: I agree, because you transform a string into an array, very bad practice.

Comment: ok. Then please give another solution .

Comment: I gave you one. Declare a new variable and store strintg_value.split('*'); in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to re-use `split` and split the values into arrays again. And then use this arrays to fill your html elements with a loop.

```js
var strintg_value="a.html+a.jpeg*b.html+b.jpeg*c.html+c.jpeg*d.html+d.jpeg*e.html+e.jpeg";

strintg_value = strintg_value.split('*');

for (var i = 0; i < strintg_value.length; ++i) {
    var element = strintg_value[i].split('+');
    $('.' + (i + 1) + '-li').find('a').attr('href', element[0]).find('img').attr('src', element[1]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="1-li normal"><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
<li class="2-li normal"><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
<li class="3-li normal"><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
<li class="4-li normal"><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
<li class="5-li normal"><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
```

Answer (score 2):

ES6 version :

```js
let strintg_value = 'a.html+a.jpeg*b.html+b.jpeg*c.html+c.jpeg*d.html+d.jpeg*e.html+e.jpeg';

strintg_value.split('*').forEach( (value,index) => {
 let s = value.split("+") // ["a.html", "a.jpeg"]
 $(`li.${index+1}-li a`).attr("href", s[0])
 $(`li.${index+1}-li img`).attr("src", s[1])
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="1-li normal"><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
<li class="2-li normal"><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
<li class="3-li normal"><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
<li class="4-li normal"><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
<li class="5-li normal"><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the string, then map and split each entry to get the link and the img src separated. Then you can just loop over the lis and set the attributes on the `a` and `img`:

```js
var str = "a.html+a.jpeg*b.html+b.jpeg*c.html+c.jpeg*d.html+d.jpeg*e.html+e.jpeg";
let s = str.split('*').map(e => e.split('+'));
let lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

for (let i = 0; i < lis.length && i < s.length; i++) {
  lis[i].querySelector('a').setAttribute('href', s[i][0]);
  lis[i].querySelector('img').setAttribute('src', s[i][1]);
}
```

```html
<li class="1-li normal">
  <a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
</li>
<li class="2-li normal">
  <a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
</li>
<li class="3-li normal">
  <a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
</li>
<li class="4-li normal">
  <a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
</li>
<li class="5-li normal">
  <a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use map after the split:

```
var strintg_value="a.html+a.jpeg*b.html+b.jpeg*c.html+c.jpeg*d.html+d.jpeg*e.html+e.jpeg";

    var formatted = strintg_value.split('*').map(function(item){
      var splitItem = item.split('+');
      return {
        link: splitItem [0],
        src: splitItem[1]
      };
    });
```

This would make the array formatted an array of objects with `link` and `src` attributes.

Answer (score 1):

First, use `strintg_value.split('*');` to turn the string into an `array`

Second, you can loop through each `li` element and apply the correct strintg_value value by using `i` to get the index.

```
var strintg_value = "a.html+a.jpeg*b.html+b.jpeg*c.html+c.jpeg*d.html+d.jpeg*e.html+e.jpeg";
strintg_value = strintg_value.split('*');

$("li[class*=-li]").each(function(i,x) {
  var href = strintg_value[i].split('+')[0];
  var src = strintg_value[i].split('+')[1];
  $(this).find("a").attr("href", href);
  $(this).find("img").attr("src", src);
})
```

```js
var strintg_value = "a.html+a.jpeg*b.html+b.jpeg*c.html+c.jpeg*d.html+d.jpeg*e.html+e.jpeg";
strintg_value = strintg_value.split('*');

$("li[class*=-li]").each(function(i,x) {
  var href = strintg_value[i].split('+')[0];
  var src = strintg_value[i].split('+')[1];
  $(this).find("a").attr("href", href);
  $(this).find("img").attr("src", src);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="1-li normal">
  <a href="#">a<img src="#" /></a>
</li>
<li class="2-li normal">
  <a href="#">b<img src="#" /></a>
</li>
<li class="3-li normal">
  <a href="#">c<img src="#" /></a>
</li>
<li class="4-li normal">
  <a href="#">d<img src="#" /></a>
</li>
<li class="5-li normal">
  <a href="#">e<img src="#" /></a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) once to split by `*` and than, loop over all the elements `document.querySelectorAll('ul li')` with [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and use the element `index` to split again but this time by `+` and from current element use [document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to query the `a` element and the `img` to make the proper update..

Code:

```js
var strintg_value = 'a.html+a.jpeg*b.html+b.jpeg*c.html+c.jpeg*d.html+d.jpeg*e.html+e.jpeg',
    arr = strintg_value.split('*');

document.querySelectorAll('ul li').forEach(function (el, index) {
  var subArr = arr[index].split('+');
  el.querySelector('a').href = subArr[0];
  el.querySelector('img').src = subArr[1];      
  console.log(el.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="1-li normal"><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
  <li class="2-li normal"><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
  <li class="3-li normal"><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
  <li class="4-li normal"><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
  <li class="5-li normal"><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
</ul>
```

With jQuery:

```js
var strintg_value = 'a.html+a.jpeg*b.html+b.jpeg*c.html+c.jpeg*d.html+d.jpeg*e.html+e.jpeg',
    arr = strintg_value.split('*');

$('ul li').each(function (index, el) {
  var subArr = arr[index].split('+');
  $(el)
    .find('a').attr('href', subArr[0])
    .find('img').attr('src', subArr[1]);      
  console.log(el.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="1-li normal"><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
  <li class="2-li normal"><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
  <li class="3-li normal"><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
  <li class="4-li normal"><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
  <li class="5-li normal"><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
//var string = 'a.html+a.jpeg*b.html+b.jpeg*c.html+c.jpeg*d.html+d.jpeg*e.html+e.jpeg';
var strintg_value="http://www.martinique.org/sites/martinique/files/plage_du_diamant_v1240_0.jpg*http://www.ajaccio-tourisme.com/sites/otajaccio/files/blocmusee_0.jpg*http://www.ajaccio-tourisme.com/sites/otajaccio/files/Cit%C3%A9-Imp%C3%A9riale.jpg*http://www.ajaccio-tourisme.com/sites/otajaccio/files/Pays-d%E2%80%99Ajaccio.jpg*http://www.ajaccio-tourisme.com/sites/otajaccio/files/Environnement.jpg";

var images = $("img[src='#']");
var url = strintg_value.split("*");
//for or objImg.each(function(index){ this.src = url[index] }
for(var n=0; n < images.length; n++){
  images[n].src = url[n];
  images[n].style = "border:solid 10px black";
}
```

```css
img{width:50px; height:50px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="1-li normal"><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
<li class="2-li normal"><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
<li class="3-li normal"><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
<li class="4-li normal"><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
<li class="5-li normal"><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
```